# Can a Full-State Keyed Sponge be used as AEAD by using XEX?

Tags: algorithm-design, authenticated-encryption, pseudo-random-permutation, sponge

[Full-State Keyed Sponge](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/541.pdf)  (aka Donkey Sponge) is when a message is absorbed into the full state of the sponge.

Such an approach to MAC construction is considered secure. [1](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/541.pdf)

However for an AEAD or a stream cipher, exposing the state obviously breaks it.

Would utilizing a XEX-like approach be able to secure such a scheme?

Let P be a permutation such as Keccak-p.
Using P we construct a duplex object such as:

[image: Ascon sponge duplex]

We modify it to no longer have a hidden state (second lane in the diagram above).

This would result in a broken cipher as the state leaks via Cx.

The proposed fix is to have

```
Cx = Px ⊕ STATE(x) ⊕ STATE(x-1)
```

Note that

```
STATE(x+1) = P(STATE(x) ⊕ Px)
```

Where

```
|Cx| = |Px| = |STATE(x)|
```

Would this work to secure the cipher? I have been unable to find any papers on the subject.

My attempt to analyze it yielded:

```
Cx = Px ⊕ STATE(x) ⊕ STATE(x-1)
Cx+1 = Px+1 ⊕ STATE(x+1) ⊕ STATE(x)
```

Meaning that an attacker could obtain:

```
STATE(x+1) ⊕ STATE(x-1)
```

Therefore, could obtain:

```
STATE(J) ⊕ STATE(J+n)
```

for any n > 0 where J is one step prior to the beginning of ciphertext extraction.

But I don't see how that can help leak the STATE at any point or lead to an attack on the cipher.

Comment: [OCH](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/Events/2023/third-workshop-on-block-cipher-modes-of-operation/documents/accepted-papers/Flexible%20Authenticated%20Encryption.pdf) uses Even-Mansour and is like OCB but with a permutation.