# Full-Block Cipher Feedback Mode as a complete AEAD with a free MAC?

Tags: block-cipher, authenticated-encryption, pseudo-random-permutation, sponge, cfb

[Full-State Keyed Sponge](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/541.pdf) (aka Donkey Sponge) appears to cross over into block cipher mode territory such as [Full Block Cipher Feedback Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_feedback_(CFB)):

[image: Full Block Cipher Feedback Mode]

Full State Keyed Sponge (FKS) construction:

[image: Full-State-Keyed-Sponge-FKS-construction]

FKS has been shown to be a secure way to obtain a MAC.[1](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/541.pdf)

FKS and Full-Block CFB are the same constructs, there apparently even exists a CFB-MAC as per: [Where is CFB-MAC defined?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27803/where-is-cfb-mac-defined)

There also exists something similar: [CBC-MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC)

[image]

---

We can transform the unkeyed permutation at the core of a sponge into a fully keyed permutation (with round keys or Even-Mansour). It would become a large state block cipher.

**Could we not use the resulting construct to perform efficient AEAD with a completely free MAC at the end?**

Sponge Duplex constructions pay for the MAC with additional compute operations on the hidden state. And given the need for multiple rounds of diffusion and confusion in the permutation, the additional operations can never compete directly on performance with one-time polynomial MACs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a Full-State Keyed Sponge be used as AEAD by using XEX?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/108263/can-a-full-state-keyed-sponge-be-used-as-aead-by-using-xex)

Comment: Appears to be unrelated to the question.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what is happening here. The link by @samuel-lucas6 to the possible duplicate question was created by by the same user (LightTunnelEnd) and it is currently unanswered. Possibly the idea is that this question would become answered if it gets an answer?

Comment: Well, he did reference OCB in the other question. OCB provides a MAC for basically free while operating in an almost-ECB mode with maximum parallelization. Also has security proofs. Still doesn't answer the question unfortunately even though it may make it moot. https://competitions.cr.yp.to/round3/ocbv11.pdf

Comment: I actually referenced OCH, which is different from OCB. It's similar to what you're discussing (uses XEX and a permutation). I don't understand how this is a different question to your previous question, but I don't see a way of voting to close this question. And you keep stating the same thing over and over again about how fast polynomial MACs are despite them not being collision resistant/generally being weaker than the sponge construction, and thus they shouldn't really be compared.

Comment: CTX/CTX+ construction replaces a tag with hmac including previous tag, it's fully committing. Putting up with low performance of Sponges is not even required for commitment. https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/Events/2023/third-workshop-on-block-cipher-modes-of-operation/documents/accepted-papers/The%20Landscape%20of%20Committing%20Authenticated%20Encryption.pdf

Comment: PCBC mode was designed this way trying to achieve free data integrity, but failed. Intermediate values from CBC-MAC must not be used for encryption. This is why different key must be used when encrypting with CBC and using CBC-MAC.